# Geometries merged with BufferGeometryUtils differ from the original model

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

When i try to merge GLB model geometries with three.js (BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries), new geometries don't always align to the original model.

Other geometries are oversimplified, such as the round window in the example.

This is the portion of code:

```
let geometries = [];
model.traverse( c => {
    if (c.isMesh){
        let clonedGeometry = c.geometry.clone();
        clonedGeometry.applyMatrix4( c.matrixWorld );
        for ( const key in clonedGeometry.attributes ) {
            if ( key === 'position' || key === 'normal' ) continue;
            clonedGeometry.deleteAttribute( key );
        }
        geometries.push( clonedGeometry );
    }
});
let mergedGeometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries( geometries );
```

How can I get merged geometries more similar to the original?

[image: original glb model, merged geometries in blue]

Comment: Does using `c.matrix` instead of `c.matrixWorld` help?

Comment: Thanks Matt Ellen: following your advice I found that the problem was generated by the coordinates of the vertices of the geometry. The 3D model is georeferenced with coordinates greater than a million for x and y. 
Representing the coordinates of the vertices referred to their minimum value, the rounding problems disappear.

Comment: Happy to provide inspiration! You should self answer in case anyone else has the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem origin**

Vertices with georeferenced coordinates have values greater than a million for x and y. Rounding errors appears.

**Solution**

- calculate minimum x and y of the vertices;
- subtract the minimum value from the coordinates;
- merge the geometries and create mesh;
- set mesh.position to minimum calculated;